# Draw polyline with GPS on google map by Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am creating a website with google-map where I set a destination between my location to my target location. After setting the distance I successfully get the route for the destination from Google Maps. Now on, I start to go from my location to the destination. But here is the problem, because I need to draw polylines on Google Maps wherever I move but my GPS did not give me the exact latitude and longitude, and the GPS also updating/moving lightly though my device is not moving.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions here in one. One is for drawing a polyline, another is for what is called "GPS drift". The GPS drift is connected to drawing polylines - you can research that separately (short answer: you can't do anything about it, GPS is not that accurate).

For the polylines, Google has really good documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

Here's an example from their docs

```js
// This example creates a 2-pixel-wide red polyline showing the path of
// the first trans-Pacific flight between Oakland, CA, and Brisbane,
// Australia which was made by Charles Kingsford Smith.
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: -180
    },
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  });
  const flightPlanCoordinates = [{
      lat: 37.772,
      lng: -122.214
    },
    {
      lat: 21.291,
      lng: -157.821
    },
    {
      lat: -18.142,
      lng: 178.431
    },
    {
      lat: -27.467,
      lng: 153.027
    },
  ];
  const flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

```html
<div id="map" style="height: 300px"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&v=weekly&channel=2" async></script>
```

Comment: But I only want to draw on the road while I move as like google map. What should I do?

Comment: The problem solved, => https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap